# Equivalence of open sets and closed sets definitions of continuous function $f:X\to Y$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to understand the proof of the following:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and $f:X\to Y$ be continuous.

$(A)$ For each open set $V$ in $Y$, the set $f^{-1}(V)$ is an open set in $X$.

$(B)$ For each closed set $B$ in $Y$, the set $f^{-1}(B)$ is an closed set in $X$.

Again, I want to show that $A\implies B$.

Before start to prove I want to say that I know the following. If $Y^{closed}\subset X$ and $U^{closed} \subset Y$ then $U^{closed} \subset X$. Same thing valids for *open set.* Let me write $\star$ to denote this property that I will mention it.

Now, Let $F\subset Y$ is closed $\iff$ $Y \backslash F$ is open in $Y$

$X \backslash f^{-1}(F) = f^{-1} (X\backslash F)$ . My question is in here. The Author wrote the following. $(X\backslash F)$ is open in $Y$ then $f^{-1}(X\backslash F)$ is open in $X$. Thus, $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed in $X$.

I can not understand how can (s)he jump like that? How can s(he) know that $(X\backslash F)$ is open in $Y$ ? I know the $\star$ property but I can not see it in here.

Comment: What does the notation "$Y^{closed} \subset X$" mean?

Comment: The proof does not use the property $\star$ you mention at all; indeed, if $f:X \to Y$, then it is generally not the case that $Y \subseteq X$. The property being used to deduce that $X \backslash F$ is open is exactly the continuity of the function $f$, as described in $(a)$.

Answer (score 1):

The complement of an open set is closed and vice versa. This is often used as a definition of an open set.

If $B$ is a closed subset of Y, then $B^c$ is open. So $f^{-1}(B^c)$ is also open by A. That means$[f^{-1}(B^c)]^c$ is closed.

What is the relationship of $f^{-1}(B)$ to $[f^{-1}(B^c)]^c$?

$x\in f^{-1}(B) \iff f(x) \in B$

$f(x)\in B \iff f(x) \notin B^c$

$f(x) \notin B^c \iff x \notin f^{-1}(B^c)\iff x\in [f^{-1}(B^c)]^c$

So $f^{-1}(B) =[f^{-1}(B^c)]^c$

So $f^{-1}(B)$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

That is just wrong. The set $F$ is a subset of $X$, not of $Y$. What happens is that $X\setminus f^{-1}(F)=f^{-1}(Y\setminus F)$, which is an open subset of $X$, since $Y\setminus F$ is an open subset of $Y$.